# Choice of SQL and DB Sharing

Tags: sql

I am trying to build a customized attendance package for a local college, there are nearly 1300 students, hence I prefer to work with SQL Compact (SQL CE) since it is free to use unlike sql server, please correct me if I am  wrong.

Also, please advice me if I could place the DB on a shared folder in network and install the software on all the PCs and insert and modify records as in normal PC does?

Thank you for your time.

TO be clear, the number of clients would be 30 approx only, and nearly 1300 records per day would be inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx)** is also free - the 2008 R2 version supports up to 10 GB in database size.

This is a full blown server product which should be a lot better suited to such an environment with lots of users hitting the database at the same time

SQL Server Compact is intended for uses where you need to store data on the user's local machine - it's definitely **not designed** to be used as a server-like product with multiple users connecting to it at the same time.

Comment: The question is edited, the no. of clients would be 30 approx and 1300 rows per day would be inserted.

Comment: @surpavan: even for 30 clients - don't use SQL CE - it's designed as a workstation-only, one-user-at-a-time database

Comment: Thank you @marc_s, I would remember that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want access database with 1300 clients, the embeded database (SQL CE, Firebird, Sqlite, etc..) is not good chouce.

For 1300 client is good full db server (SQL Server Express or similar edition of Oracle etc...) or some custom service (i.e. web services).

Comment: The question is edited, the no. of clients would be 30 approx and 1300 rows per day would be inserted.

Comment: The 30 clients process *.mdb database. It's one of embeded database which can serve more clients at on time. However it's on the oedge of usability. The maintenence will be higher than full server.

Comment: Could you clarify it a bit more detail, also, please advice what to do?  Thank you.

Comment: I agree with @marc_s, the SQL Server Express looks perfect for your project.

Comment: Fine, thanks for the comments, since I am going to do 1300rows of data per day, I would use SQL Express and also it would be a good choice since more clients are involved.  Thanks for informing all these things to me.